# Netbeans cloning from GitHub ending up with an empty project

Tags: git, netbeans, github

So I'm running Team > Git > Clone from remote and entering the URL for my GitHub repository. I enter my login information and it tells me it successfully clones and it shows up in the repo browser, but no files appear in the newly created project. What obvious thing am I completely missing that would tell me where these files should show up in the new project?

Comment: What repo is it? Are you sure it has files in it? Did you set the destination folder? Are you looking there for the files?  Are you looking in the project tab or the files tab? The project tab will hide files it doesn't recognize.

Comment: It is a private repo. It has several java and txt files as well as a folder of pictures. I have set the destination folder and afterwards create a project from the files in the clone wizard. I am looking in the project tab and the file tab and the files are not displaying. They are in the destination folder under C:\Users\administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects.

Is it possible to create a project from an assortment of .java's in netbeans? I didn't think that it would have a problem but it makes sense, given all the extra files it needs to understand a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is there is something wrong with the project files you checked out, like an incorrect  path. You can check where it expects sources, by right clicking the project, choosing Properties and select Sources on the left. Under Source Packages it lists where it searches for source files. Normally this is just the relative path `src`. If you know the correct folder you can add it there.

You can also create a new project with menu option File -> New Project, select category Java and type `Java with Existing Sources` and then add the top-level directory where your .java files ended up.

Just to be clear if the file SomeClass.java contains the line 'package abc;' then it needs to be in a sub-directory called abc. If you find the file SomeClass.java in

```
C:\Users\administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\somerepo\somedir\abc\SomeClass.java
```

then the source folder to add would be

```
C:\Users\administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\somerepo\somedir
```

or a relative path from your project directory, so that you can add `\abc\SomeClass.java` to get the fullpath to that file.

Also I wouldn't normally do development as Administrator. Are you sure there is not a permissions problem with Netbeans accessing that directory?